# What are these "retry-request" logs generated from a Firestore docRef.get() call?

Tags: firebase, debugging, logging, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I've never seen this logs before, but now that I've added the `debug` package to my server, they started appearing:

[image]

**Text version:**

```
> retry-request Current retry attempt: 1 + 0ms
> retry-request Response status: undefined +214ms
```

This is coming from from a file that does the following firestore get call:

```
(await db.collection(MY_COLLECTION).doc(MY_DOC).get()).data()
```

I'm pretty sure that this is causing those logs, because when I removed this piece of the code (which is the only firestore-related code on that file), those logs were no longer shown.

What do they mean? Can I get rid of them or should I keep'em?

Comment: Is the log transient or does it appear whenever the call is made?

Comment: I haven't tested it thoroughly to be sure it would happen every time 100%, but 3 of my route handlers that contained a `firebase-admin` firestore `docRef.get()` did that every time I ran them. I tested each file a couple of times. Anyway, I uninstalled the `debug` package for other reasons, so I guess I won't be seeing those anymore.